Incoming webhook -> AdaptiveCard
I am new to this Adaptive Card. I am trying to create a Jira card in teams so i did following workflow.
In Jira i call the webhook and all works. I can see data flows and no errors however my Adaptive Card which is :
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "size": "Medium",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "text": "${fields.summary}"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "${fields.description}",
        "wrap": true
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0" 
}

Now in teams i get a notification in the channel but the ${fields.summary} doesn't get replaced with the real data. I tried ${body.fields.summary}, ${body.issue.fields.summary} and ```${issue.fields.summary}`` and none shows the data.
I only see this :

Is there some schemas or something i need to do ?
/donnib


No, you need to populate that data into the adaptive card using a proper expression. That syntax you’ve shown is used when data is bound via a framework. You don’t do that in PowerAutomate, you just fill the values.

Thank you but i am not sure what you mean, do you mean i have to call the webhook with the proper JSON format for Adaptive Card ? If that's the case i can't control that, jira just calls the webhook and sends the data in it's format in JSON which then i need to pick out and show accordingly in an adaptive card. If i need to do it otherwise then i need a middle man unless i can change the JSON that comes from the webhook in Power Automate to the format that the Adaptive Card requires.

No, you have to build the json which is the adaptive card. There’s no binding framework, you literally have to build the json which is the card. That means translating the data that comes in, into the json that is the card.

Ok but can i translate that in the Power Automate somehow ? I mean adding some steps ?

Yes, literally, you have to build the json. That means building up arrays and injecting the array into a larger json, filling textual values that may represent labels on the card with dynamic values from your flow, etc. I can’t give you anymore than that because your question is not targeted, it’s quite generic. If you haven’t used expressions in PA before, Google “LogicApps expressions” … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference

"Is there some schemas or something i need to do?"
Yes, the way I was able to resolve this issue is that I added an extra step between the Webhook and the Postcard to get the JSON payload from the body of the incoming Webhook's payload.

Add the Parse JSON action between the webhook and the Postcard.
For the Content of the Parse JSOn, select Body from the Dynamic content.
Generate the Schema from the JSON payload or JSON data that you have.
enter image description here
In the Post card action, you will be able to access the output of the Parse JSON's output.

